# Finding the MLE estimate from a log function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, maximum-likelihood, log-likelihood

If I have the following function:
$$\ln L(\mu,\sigma^2)= -n \ln (\sqrt{2 \pi \sigma^2})+\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{-(x_i-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}$$

How can I find the MLE estimate $σ^2_\text{MLE}$?

I have already shown that $\mu = \bar{x}$

Comment: Take the partial derivative with respect to $\sigma^2$. Treat it as one variable.

Comment: I got that $\sigma^2 = \frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2n}$, does that sound correct?

Comment: @Hannah : What is "$x$"? Do you mean $\overline x \text{ ?} \qquad$

Answer (score 0):

$$
\ln L(\mu,\sigma^2)= -n \ln \sqrt{2 \pi \sigma^2} - \frac 1 {2\sigma^2} \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\mu)^2
$$

You report that you have shown that the value of $\mu$ that maximizes this is $\overline x = (x_1+\cdots+x_n)/n.$

One could say that this is with $\sigma$ fixed, but more to the point, this result is the same regardless of $\sigma.$ And for any here who have not noticed this before, it is of interest to note that this is just the value of $\mu$ that minimizes $\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\mu)^2,$ and that the best way to see that is via the identity in algebra that says
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\mu)^2 = n(\mu-\overline x)^2 + \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\overline x)^2.
$$

What is sought is the pair $(\mu,\sigma^2)$ that maximizes $L(\mu,\sigma^2),$ and that is the same as the pair that maximizes $\ln L(\mu,\sigma^2),$ and that expression is used because it requires less work to get to the answer.

The maximizing value of $\mu$ with $\sigma^2$ fixed is the same regardless of $\sigma^2,$ and consequently we can just find the value of $\sigma^2$ that maximizes $L(\overline x,\sigma^2)$.

\begin{align}
\ln L(\overline x,\sigma^2) & = -n \ln \sqrt{2 \pi \sigma^2} - \frac 1 {2\sigma^2} \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\overline x)^2 \\[8pt]
& = -n\ln \sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2} - \frac{ns^2}{2\sigma^2} \\[8pt]
& = \text{constant} -\frac n 2 \ln (\sigma^2) - \frac{ns^2}{2\sigma^2}. \tag 1
\end{align}
I prefer to write that last line as $\text{constant}-n\ln\sigma - \dfrac{ns^2}{2\sigma^2}$ and differentiate with respect to $\sigma,$ but I've noticed various authorities preferring to treat $\sigma^2$ as a simple thing, so here I will do it that way.

The derivative of $(1)$ with respect to $\sigma^2$ is
$$
- \frac n {2\sigma^2} + \frac{ns^2}{2(\sigma^2)^2} = n\cdot\frac{s^2-\sigma^2}{\sigma^4} \quad \begin{cases} >0 & \text{if } 0<\sigma^2<s^2 \\ =0 & \text{if } \sigma^2=s^2, \\ <0 & \text{if } \sigma^2 > s^2. \end{cases}
$$
So this function of $\sigma^2$ increases on the interval $(0,\sigma^2]$ and decreases on the interval $[\sigma^2,+\infty).$ Therefore it has a glabal maximum at $\sigma^2 = s^2.$

Comment: ...this is the same result

Comment: @Stacker : But one should not unthinkingly seek a value at which the derivative is $0$ and say that's the MLE. For example, the MLE of $\theta>0$ based on an i.i.d. sample from a uniform distribution on the interval $(0,\theta)$ is an endpoint maximum, not a point at which the derivative is $0. \qquad$

Comment: I don't know what triggered you but taking the derivative is correct here. As for unthinkingly, that's more of your opinion.

Comment: @Stacker : No, you didn't write anything about how you went from the fact that the derivative is $0$ at a certain point to the conclusion that there is a global maximum there.

Comment: Since I haven't really read my chapters on MLE, I will assume your complaints are canonical and not going out of the statistician's way to verify an MLE.

Comment: @Stacker : The relevant chapters would be (1) on calculus: You need to do more than just show that the derivative is $0$ at a point to conclude there is a global maximum there, and (2) on reasoning: You don't just proceed algorithmically; you understand and explain.

Comment: It seems to me like you should explicitly state the connection between global maximum and MLE, because you're just repeating yourself now. And the reasoning part is definitely your opinion.

Answer (score -1):

Take the derivative wrt $\sigma^2$:

$$-\frac n {\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}\cdot \frac{2\pi}{2\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}+\frac{\sum -(x-\mu)^2}{2}\cdot \frac{-1}{(\sigma^2)^2}=0\\
=\frac{-2n\pi}{4\pi\sigma^2}+\frac{\sum(x-\mu)^2}{2(\sigma^2)^2}\\
\frac{n}{2\sigma^2}=\frac{\sum(x-\mu)^2}{2(\sigma^2)^2}\\
\sigma^2=\frac{\sum(x-\mu)^2}{n}$$

**Elaborate verification**

To be rigorous, we need to show that this value of $\sigma^2$ maximizes the density. The first derivative is $$\frac{-n}{2\sigma^2}+\frac{\sum(x-\mu)^2}{(\sigma^2)^2}?0\\
-\sigma^2+\frac{\sum(x-\mu)^2}{n}?0$$

where the question mark  represents an unknown relationship. We can see that the derivative is 0 at $\sum(x-\mu)^2/n$. When $\sigma^2$ is greater than this, the first derivative is negative, and when it is less than this, the first derivative is positive. So we can conclude that $\sigma^2$ is a *global maximum*. For fun, I also take the second derivative.

$$\frac{\partial^2}{(\partial \sigma^2)^2}\log l(\sigma^2|\mathbf x)=\frac{n}{2(\sigma^2)^2}-\frac{\sum(x-\mu)^2}{(\sigma^2)^3}\\
\sigma^2-\frac{2\sum(x-\mu)^2}{n}?0$$

This is zero when $\sigma^2$ is $\frac{2\sum(x-\mu)^2}{n}$, positive when it is greater than that, and negative when it is less than that. So there is an inflection point at $\frac{2\sum(x-\mu)^2}{n}$, the log likelihood is concave up when $\sigma^2$ is greater than that, and concave down when it is less than that.

[image]

**Conclusion**

$\sigma^2_{MLE}=\frac{\sum(x-\bar x)^2}{n}$

Comment: This neglects the fact that $\mu$ was one of the arguments to the likelihood function, i.e. it was a function of TWO variables. It also neglects the fact that a point at which a derivative is $0$ is not the same as a global maximum point.

Comment: It says mu is given. It is unclear if you read that

Comment: @MichaelHardy like this? I showed more work to be more rigorous